# How to have custom page template in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, templates

I developped a theme for Wordpress for one of my client and in that order, I created multiple pages in html for the moment. Except my index (static homepage) using the "single" template I think, I have other pages (each one is different and using different style CSS).

Is it possible, and how should I create and name the custom PHP pages in order to get each page displayed by its own html basis and styling?

Didn't find any matching answer on the internet yet, just general stuff about pages in wordpress, not custom ones.

Thank you a lot by advance if you can help me!

Comment: Maybe the wordpress documentation will help you with that: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page -- there's also mention how to create a global page template, if you create one or more of them, you can then inside your page specify which template to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate php file for each webpage

Name each php file what ever you like, it does not matter

Add a template name at the very top of each php file

```
/*
Template Name: Unique Name

The template is for ....

*/
```

Open the wordpress backend with wp-admin and press create new webpage. When creating the new page select the template name you want.

Done !

Comment: Thank you a lot, your answer and the one above you helped me pretty much, also with the wordpress documentation (which I didn't found online for my case).

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to completely understand the problem. I notice you have `.html`  theme and you want to use this template as page template. In this case you have to create a file in the root of theme with name: `cutome1-page.php` and this file needs to start with the following line:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custome1 Page  */ ?>
```

after that, while you create page in wordpress panel, you see a template as : Custome1 Page